# I am looking a way to auto convert documents in Sharepoint Work Flow to auto convert to PDF

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am looking for a way to convert Existing Word, Excel to auto-convert to PDF using a SharePoint Workflow.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint designer workflow or Microsoft flow??

Comment: I am happy using both! Thanks @GaneshSanap

Comment: Check [this](https://natechamberlain.com/2017/10/03/convert-sharepoint-documents-to-pdf-automatically-using-microsoft-flow/) & [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Convert-SharePoint-Word-Doc-to-PDF/td-p/181641) for free but complex solutions and [this](https://support.muhimbi.com/hc/en-us/articles/228090727-About-the-PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint-Online) for paid but powerful solution to achieve the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GaneshSanap appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Designer Workflow, per my knowledge you may need to use some custom converter to convert documents to PDF.

If you have access to MS flow, you can do it OOB. There is an action called Convert file in OneDrive for business which enables you to convert file to PDF.

Below is my sample flow. 
[image]

You can refer these threads for detailed articles:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Converting-Word-Doc-to-PDF-Creates-a-pdf-pdf-File/td-p/172175
https://www.breadcrumbdigital.com.au/using-flow-to-convert-word-documents-to-pdfs-in-just-six-easy-steps/

Comment: I appreciate your solution! Thank you very much

Comment: @TejasThite Glad to be your help. It the reply solves your issue, you can mark it as answer.